# Change object in array if found by id

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

According to Redux design patterns if you want to change object in array, you have to use state.items.map, but is it ok to use array.findIndex and if item not found return old state? Is it bad practices, if yes why?

1. Redux pattern method. Method returns new state, even if room not found.

   `const roomId = action.payload.room.id;
       const roomsList = state.roomsList.map(room => {
           if (room.id === roomId) {
              return action.payload.room;
           } else {
              return room;
           }
       });
       return {
           ...state,
           roomsList,
       };`
2. Second way, that I like more. Method returns new state only if room with given ID is found

   `const roomId = action.payload.room.id;
       const idx = state.roomsList.findIndex(room => room.id === roomId);
       if(idx!==-1) {
           const roomsList = Array.from(state.roomsList);
           roomsList[idx] = action.payload.room;
           return {
               ...state,
               roomsList,
           };
       }else{
           return state;
       }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **always** okay to return the previous state if a reducer did not make any changes.

That's what the `default` case typically does in the usual `switch` within a reducer function, like in [the example from the official `redux` docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#reducersjs).